# jquery ajax query is executed twice

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have form with user data to input and javascript ajax to send information on server and handle it with php to send this info on email, but when i submit, ajax send this informatio twice
 javascript:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "<?php echo JURI::root(). " / components / com_searchtour / handler.php " ?>",
  data: {
    'birthday': $("#birthday").val(),
    'name': $("#name").val(),
    'name2': $("#name2").val(),
    'name3': $("#name3").val(),
  },
  success: function(html) {
    $('div#text_after_submit').append("<h2>Отправлено</h2>");
  }
});
return false;
```

found the problem i have some code below this

```
$(function(){
                          $.datepicker.setDefaults(
                                $.extend($.datepicker.regional["ru"])
                          );
```

when i remove it, now all works fine :) thanks everyone for help

Comment: how will this ajax call executed? could you pls provide more code snippets, which executes this call?

Comment: **wat executed twice?** you got the success function execute twice or the mail was sent twice? try putting an alert in the success part and check whether it executes twice.

Comment: Where did u call this function paste some code. Who votes this vague question

Comment: Does this ajax called attach to some event? maybe it's the wrong event? like onclick of the button and no onsubmit of the form...

Comment: i do my ajax request on $('#form_pasp').submit(function()

Comment: also i have form with jquery.tab()

Comment: function(event){ e.preventDefault(); $.ajax(...)}

Comment: added alert("form submitted") - got two alerts  and two mails was sent

Comment: probably the form itself will be submitted again, after the ajax call has been done, so the form submit event won't be catched? Do you see a site refresh, after the submit?

Comment: Daxcode, nope i dont see site refresh after submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "<?php echo JURI::root(). " / components / com_searchtour / handler.php " ?>",
  data: {
    'birthday': $("#birthday").val(),
    'name': $("#name").val(),
    'name2': $("#name2").val(),
    'name3': $("#name3").val(),
  },
  success: function(html) {
    $('div#text_after_submit').append("<h2>Отправлено</h2>");
  }

  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function(event){ e.preventDefault(); $
```

`event` and `e` are two different var names, so the submit event won't be catched.

try to substitute `event` with `e`.